# NSIS: Componesnts page on component checked event

Tags: installation, nsis

I using NSIS to install my project. I need to show MessageBox with warning text, when I choosing some section to install on components page. Is there some way to track the click on the checkbox, may be event or something?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation page? http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Reference/MessageBox
You will probably want to use `MB_ICONEXCLAMATION`

Comment: @MateoConLechuga I mean check event (click on checkbox control), not show a message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [.onSelChange callback](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#callbacks).

In NSIS 3 the changed section id is stored in $0:

```
Page Components
Page InstFiles

Section /o "Foo" SID_FOO
SectionEnd

Section "Bar"
SectionEnd

!include LogicLib.nsh

Function .onSelChange
${If} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SID_FOO}
${AndIf} $0 = ${SID_FOO}
    MessageBox MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "Warning, section Foo selected!"
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

You have to track the state yourself in NSIS 2:

```
Page Components
Page InstFiles

Section /o "Foo" SID_FOO
SectionEnd

Section "Bar"
SectionEnd

!include LogicLib.nsh

Var hasWarned

Function .onSelChange
${If} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SID_FOO}
${AndIf} $hasWarned = 0
    StrCpy $hasWarned 1
    MessageBox MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "Warning, section Foo selected!"
${EndIf}
/* Uncomment this to display the warning every time it is selected
${IfNot} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SID_FOO}
    StrCpy $hasWarned 0
${EndIf}
*/
FunctionEnd
```